# Quick Reference for LLDB?

Tags: debugging, lldb

I'm familiar with single- and double-page quick reference "cards" for GDB, and have found them quite useful.

Now that our project is using LLDB I'd like to find an equivalent for that tool, but I've had little luck finding one as quickly as I would have expected.

Does one exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the [LLDB to GDB Command Map](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html)? It would need to be reformatted if you want it in a reference card style layout, but it's already written like one.

Answer (score 0):

I just started learning lldb. So far:

```
    $lldb a.out [args]  
    (lldb)r    -->run  
    (lldb)b 22 -->breakpoint at linenumber 22 )  
    (lldb)l    -->list your code  
    (lldb)n    -->next step  
    (lldb)s    -->step
```